Where is ZFS keeping record of my faulted disks?
I had multiple drives in a ZFS array drop due to read errors yesterday. After powering down the machine to swap in a replacement for one of the drives, I was surprised to find that the drives previously labeled as FAULTED as ONLINE.
I kept record of the previously faulted disks, so which ones in the array that went down are not a mystery. However, I cannot find any way to lookup this information. I did not see any record of the fault in dmesg and there isn't anything relevant in /var/log/messages after rebooting.
Where does ZFS record the information on which drives it had previously labeled as FAULTED?
I am using OpenZFS 0.7.12-1 on CentOS 7.8.
